# Rendering the add to cart form

Tags: 8, commerce

Is it possible to render the add to cart form programatically? Something like:

```
\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('Drupal\commerce_cart\Form\AddToCartForm', $product)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, possible and very easy.

**Short version**

You can use this render array.

This will render the Cart form if your product can be added to cart - if it has available variations bascially.

```
$combine = TRUE;
$langcode = 'en';
$view_mode = 'cart';

$build['add_to_cart_form'] = [
  '#lazy_builder' => [
    'commerce_product.lazy_builders:addToCartForm', [
      $product_id,
      $view_mode,
      $combine,
      $langcode
    ],
  ],
  '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
];
```

---

**Full example with a Controller**

You can use a custom Controller to render your own *Add To Cart* form.

First, prepare the route in `mymodule.routing.yml`:

```
# Custom route to render Add to cart form.
mymodule.add_to_cart:
  path: '/mymodule/add_to_cart/{product_id}'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\CartController::addToCart'
    _title: 'Add to cart'
  requirements:
    _access: 'TRUE'
    product_id: \d+
```

Second, create your Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller routines for cart routes.
 */
class CartController extends ControllerBase {

  function addToCart(int $product_id) {
    $build = [];

    if (!$product_id) {
      $build['error'] = [
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#markup' => $this->t('Wrong product ID'),
      ];
      return $build;
    }

    $build['add_to_cart_form'] = [
      '#lazy_builder' => [
        'commerce_product.lazy_builders:addToCartForm', [
          $product_id,
          'cart',
          TRUE,
          'fr'
        ],
      ],
      '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
    ];

    return $build;
  }

}
```

Finally, add a link to open a modal on front end, as follow:

```
<a href="/mymodule/add_to_cart/1234" title="Add to cart" class="use-ajax" data-dialog-type="modal" data-dialog-options="{&quot;width&quot;:700}">Add product to cart</a>
```

Clear cache

You should be good to go! :)